# python mysqldb err on my mac :Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb
```

leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.13-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/simon/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/simon/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found`
```

I try to build and install mysql-python, and `ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dyli`, but can not resolve it

Answer (score 3):

So, from what I can tell, the @rpath tries to resolve to /usr/lib, which can't be written to. I resolved this by crawling through [this site](https://blog.csdn.net/zhtsuc/article/details/50804846). A lot of it is in Chinese, but what I got was the command sudo `install_name_tool -change @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /Users/[username]/.pyenv/versions/career/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so`

Comment: This works without needing to implement csrutil.

Comment: This works, however, you need to dig out where the .so file is. In my case it was in the virtual's environment lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to what Sam did and was able to make it work.

I simply made a copy of the `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` file located in my up-to-date installation of MySQL 8.0.13 which is was in `/usr/local/mysql/lib` and moved that copy under the same name to `/usr/lib`.

You will need to temporarily disable security integrity protection on your mac however to do this since you won't have or be able to change permissions to anything in `/usr/lib` without disabling it.  You can do this by booting up into the recovery system, click Utilities on the menu at the top, and open up the terminal and enter `csrutil disable` into the terminal.  Just remember to turn security integrity protection back on when you're done doing this!  The only difference from the above process will be that you run `csrutil enable` instead.

You can find out more about how to disable and enable macOS's security integrity protection [here](https://support.accountek.com/support/solutions/articles/6000101816-odb-1-61d-install-disabling-sip-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-os-el-capitan-10-11-).

Comment: After I rebooted, set "csrutil disable", rebooted again and came back to try again in /usr/lib, I got: "ln: ./libmysqlclient.21.dylib: Read-only file system". So no joy.

Comment: Well. Got around it. "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/local/mysql-8.0.19-macos10.15-x86_64/lib python3 mything.py". A bit of a PITA but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for rustc as well,I can confirm that the solution

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:<path_to_where_libmysqlclient_is>`

worked for me on Mac Sonoma 14.
I had  libmysqlclient.23.dylib , and compiler was locking for  libmysqlclient.20.dylib, so I just created a symlink pointing to libmysqlclient.23.dylib!

Hope this helps someone!'
due credit to @Ray Kiddy!!