# in Flask MySQL and SqlAlchemy command db.create_all() give error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

After entering `from app import db` and `db.create_all()` in terminal above error comes

Comment: did you install database MySQL ? It may need also some of Python's modules to work with MySQL - ie. `mysql-connector`

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy so don't need mysql-connector

Comment: You need one of the MySQL DB-API drivers, be it mysql-connector, mysql-python aka MySQLdb, or pymysql. SQLAlchemy does not talk directly to the DB itself.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590645/library-not-loaded-rpath-libmysqlclient-21-dylib-reason-image-not-found-djang, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536914/pythons-mysqldb-can-t-find-libmysqlclient-dylib-with-homebrewed-mysql, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002735/python-mysqldb-err-on-my-mac-library-not-loaded-rpath-libmysqlclient-21-dylib, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib?

Comment: I have successfully disable SIP, now what is the next step, when I run following command it says file already exist. ```sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib```

Comment: I did most of the above still showing same error

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create virtual environment
Step 2: Install all necessary module e.g. Flask, SQLAlchemy, however, you won't be able to install MySQLDB so instead of that use `pip install pymysql`
Step 3: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:Vrishab2145@localhost/testOne'`
In step 3, must add mysql+pymysql

Hureyy..... It worked for me 
Important is creating virtual environment. You don't need to go through nasty SSL and other things